# Como gerar um jar através do ANT?

Tags: java, jar, ant

estou utilizando o Jdeveloper em conjunto com o Ant, entretanto me deparei com uma situação bem chata... eu nao consigo gerar um .jar funcional através do ant.

Eu ja constrúi um build.xml que contem o caminho pra main class, entretanto... sempre quando tento executar o jar que foi gerado, eu recebo a menssagem:

"cannot load or find main class"

Quando criamos um profile de deploy no Jdeveloper, construimos uma espécie de manifest, apontando pra classe principal e carregando as demais classes para dentro. Eu gostaria de saber se é preciso gerar esse manifest antes, e por fim quais itens eu devo inserir dentro do manifest... somente as classes do meu projeto?

E se eu tiver um outro projeto como dependencia do meu projeto principal? Isso deve ser apontado no build/xml ou no manifest?

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="build.dir" value="/home/wender/" />
<property name="jar.name" value="meuQuerido.jar" />

<!-- Diretório onde sua IDE gera os .class -->
<property name="dir.compilacao.java" value="c:/No/Eclipse/fica/em/no/diretorioDoMeuWorkspace/MeuProjeto/bin" />

<jar destfile="${build.dir}${jar.name}">
    <manifest>
        <!-- Substitua org.minha.Main.class pela sua (caminho completo)-->
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.minha.Main.class" />
    </manifest>
    <fileset dir="${dir.compilacao.java}"/>
        <include name="**/*.class" />
    </fileset>
</jar>
```